# Is there documentation or a resource for valid style properties and values for React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React and React Native and I'm seeking a list of reliable reference for styling my react components.

Comment: One quick way to see what is available is to open up your dev console and type `document.body.style.`

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. In addtion, we don't do *make me a list* questions here on any topic.

Answer (score 1):

All properties are the same as CSS. However you just have to write them a little differently...it's foreign at first but actually pretty simple.

- All variables are the camel-case variants of the original CSS. Treat dashes as a space so `margin-right` -> `marginRight`
- All non-numerical values should be a string

Past that it's just about expressing your CSS as a JavaScript object. For example:

```
{
  color: 'red',
  marginRight: '10px',
  opacity: 1,
}
```